# Routing error on Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I'm working on a profile page, so the config is like this:

```
routes.rb
=> match "user/:login(*path)" => 'users#profile', :as => :profile
rake routes
=> profile    /user/:login(*path)(.:format)    {:action=>"profile", :controller=>"users"}
on console
> Rails.application.routes.recognize_path("/user/example/whatever")
=> {:action=>"profile", :login=>"example", :controller=>"users", :path=>"/whatever"}
```

And I have a profile action in UsersControllers.
But when I use

```
<%= link_to user.name, profile_path(user.login) %>
```

in a view I get the error

```
No route matches {:login=>"example", :controller=>"users", :action=>"profile"}
```

What am I missing?
Thanks

**Update:**
Thanks for the answer and attention, Steve!

After a lot of time trying, a coworker find what I was missing: the problem was only with some logins that are emails too, with "@", ".", etc. The solution was adding **to_url** at params[:login] in link_to:

```
<%= link_to 'name', profile_path(params[:login].to_url) %>
```

Again, thanks for the attention!

Answer (score 0):

Using your configuration, the route and helper seem to work fine in a Rails 3.0.5 sample app.

I verified the route helper profile_path in the Rails console:

```
>> app.profile_path('example')
=> "/user/example"
```

and checked that it worked in the view as well:

```
<%= link_to 'name', profile_path(params[:login]) %>
```

No route errors in either place. And putting <%= debug(params) %> in the view shows the path '/user/example/whatever' is being parsed correctly:

```
--- !map:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess 
controller: users
action: profile
login: example
path: /whatever
```